# Get RAW Bayer pixel data from CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: ios, image-processing, cvpixelbuffer

I am using `AVCaptureSession` & `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to capture RAW photo data from device's camera in the `kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_RGGB` format.

I have got as far as getting the raw photo sample buffer in the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` callback:

```
func capture(captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
             didFinishProcessingRawPhotoSampleBuffer rawSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
             previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
             resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
             bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
             error: Error?) {

  guard let rawSampleBuffer = rawSampleBuffer else { return }

  guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(rawSampleBuffer) else { return }
}
```

I am now attempting to follow the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569750/get-pixel-value-from-cvpixelbufferref-in-swift) to obtain pixel values from the `CVPixelBufferRef` but I cannot work out how to do this when using the 14 bit Bayer RGGB pixel format as opposed to the 32 bit RGB format mentioned in the answers.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I did not get any answer

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the "Pixel format type" of the buffer. This is done with the [CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456851-cvpixelbuffergetpixelformattype?language=objc) function.

The available types are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelformatdescription/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers?changes=l_8_5). In your case I'm guessing `kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_BGGR`.

Then you need to know how the data is stored. According to [What is a CVPixelBuffer in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822136/what-is-a-cvpixelbuffer-in-ios) it is

> "Bayer 14-bit Little-Endian, packed in 16-bits, ordered R G R G... alternating with G B G B..."

Then you extract the pixels for `Uint16` the same way they did for `Uint8` in [Get pixel value from CVPixelBufferRef in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569750/get-pixel-value-from-cvpixelbufferref-in-swift).